# How to draw round rectangle using canvas and svg?

Tags: canvas, svg

I am trying to draw round rectangle using canvas and svg and I want to change rectangle color when I mouse over it. Is it possible using canvas & svg? I want something like this. Here's my link below:-
https://fxfactory.com/downloads/docs/noiseindustries/fxfactorypro/Thumbnails/Rounded%20Rectangle.jpg

Comment: Context.strokeRect does it without svg

Answer (score 3):

SVG (scalable vector graphics) and HTML Canvas are two separate technologies.
SVG is XML based and can be written inside html code as a specific set of tags:

```
<svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(128,128,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,255)" />
</svg>
```

HTML Canvas is just a canvas for the graphics created with javascript:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"
style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
</script>
```

Here it is in action:
http://codepen.io/1GR3/pen/ZpaPJR

Comment: But you can draw svg in canvas and append a canvas in svg (note that you can't draw on a canvas appended to an svg drawn on a canvas, following ?)

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do in SVG.

```css
.myrect {
  fill: red;
}

.myrect:hover {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="200">
  <rect class="myrect" x="10" y="10" width="280" height="180" rx="40" ry="40"/>
</svg>
```